# Error "Uncaught TypeError: this.containerDim is undefined" when i open more than 1 tab use firefox, it working normal when i use chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am using firefox to open my page but when I open multiple tabs, the browser console error "Uncaught TypeError: this.containerDim is undefined". If I only open 1 tab then it works fine. This doesn't happen in chrome. Can someone answer for me?
Here is full code error

```js
/*** picture view plugin ****/
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    //an empty function
    var noop = function () {};

    var $body = $('body'),
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);


    //constants
    var ZOOM_CONSTANT = 15; //increase or decrease value for zoom on mouse wheel
    var MOUSE_WHEEL_COUNT = 5; //A mouse delta after which it should stop preventing default behaviour of mouse wheel

    //ease out method
    /*
        t : current time,
        b : intial value,
        c : changed value,
        d : duration
    */

    function easeOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d;
        t--;
        return -c * (t * t * t * t - 1) + b;
    };
    
    //function to check if image is loaded
    function imageLoaded(img) {
        return img.complete && (typeof img.naturalWidth === 'undefined' | img.naturalWidth !== 0);
    }

    var imageViewHtml = '<div class="iv-loader-ss"></div> <div class="iv-snap-view-ss">' + '<div class="iv-snap-image-wrap-ss">' + '<div class="iv-snap-handle-ss"></div>' + '</div>' + '<div class="iv-zoom-slider-ss" id="slider_zoom"><div class="iv-zoom-handle-ss"></div></div></div>' + '<div class="iv-image-view-ss" ><div class="iv-image-wrap-ss" ></div></div>';
    //var imageViewHtml = '<div class="iv-zoom-slider id="slider_zoom"><div class="iv-zoom-handle"></div></div>';

    var slider_zoom = '<div class="iv-zoom-slider">' + '<div class="iv-zoom-handle"></div>' + '</div>';


    function Slider(container, options) {
        this.container = container;
        this.onStart = options.onStart || noop;
        this.onMove = options.onMove || noop;
        this.onEnd = options.onEnd || noop;
        this.sliderId = options.sliderId || 'slider' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000000);
    }

    Slider.prototype.init = function () {
        var self = this,
            container = this.container,
            eventSuffix = '.' + this.sliderId;

        //assign event on snap image wrap
        this.container.on('touchstart' + eventSuffix + ' mousedown' + eventSuffix, function (estart) {
          estart.preventDefault();
            var touchMove = (estart.type == "touchstart" ? "touchmove" : "mousemove") + eventSuffix,
                touchEnd = (estart.type == "touchstart" ? "touchend" : "mouseup") + eventSuffix,
                eOrginal = estart.originalEvent,
                sx = eOrginal.clientX || eOrginal.touches[0].clientX,
                sy = eOrginal.clientY || eOrginal.touches[0].clientY;

            var start = self.onStart(estart, {
                x: sx,
                y: sy
            });

            if (start === false) return;

            var moveListener = function (emove) {

                emove.preventDefault();

                eOrginal = emove.originalEvent;

                //get the cordinates
                var mx = eOrginal.clientX,
                    my = eOrginal.clientY;

                self.onMove(emove, {
                    dx: mx - sx,
                    dy: my - sy,
                    mx: mx,
                    my: my
                });

            };

            var endListener = function () {
                $document.off(touchMove, moveListener);
                $document.off(touchEnd, endListener);
                self.onEnd();
            };

            $document.on(touchMove, moveListener);
            $document.on(touchEnd, endListener);
        });

        return this;
    }


    function ImageViewerss(container, options) {
        var self = this;

        if (container.is('#iv-container-ss')) {
            self._fullPage = true;
        }

        self.container = container;
        options = self.options = $.extend({}, ImageViewerss.defaults, options);

        self.zoomValue = 100;

        if (!container.find('.snap-view').length) {
            //container.append(slider_zoom)
            container.prepend(imageViewHtml);
            
        }

        container.addClass('iv-container-ss');

        if (container.css('position') == 'static') container.css('position', 'relative');

        self.snapView = container.find('.iv-snap-view-ss');
        self.snapImageWrap = container.find('.iv-snap-image-wrap-ss');
        self.imageWrap = container.find('.iv-image-wrap-ss');
        self.snapHandle = container.find('.iv-snap-handle-ss');
        self.zoomHandle = container.find('.iv-zoom-handle-ss');
        self._viewerId = 'iv' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    }


    ImageViewerss.prototype = {
        constructor: ImageViewerss,
        _init: function () {
            var viewerss = this,
                options = viewerss.options,
                zooming = false, // tell weather we are zooming trough touch
                container = this.container;

            var eventSuffix = '.' + viewerss._viewerId;

            //cache dom refrence
            var snapHandle = this.snapHandle;
            var snapImgWrap = this.snapImageWrap;
            var imageWrap = this.imageWrap;

            var snapSlider = new Slider(snapImgWrap, {
                sliderId: viewerss._viewerId,

                onStart: function () {

                    if (!viewerss.loaded) return false;

                    var handleStyle = snapHandle[0].style;

                    this.curHandleTop = parseFloat(handleStyle.top);
                    this.curHandleLeft = parseFloat(handleStyle.left);
                    this.handleWidth = parseFloat(handleStyle.width);
                    this.handleHeight = parseFloat(handleStyle.height);
                    this.width = snapImgWrap.width();
                    this.height = snapImgWrap.height();

                    //stop momentum on image
                    clearInterval(imageSlider.slideMomentumCheck);
                    cancelAnimationFrame(imageSlider.sliderMomentumFrame);
                },
                onMove: function (e, position) {
                    var xPerc = this.curHandleLeft + position.dx * 100 / this.width,
                        yPerc = this.curHandleTop + position.dy * 100 / this.height;

                    xPerc = Math.max(0, xPerc);
                    xPerc = Math.min(100 - this.handleWidth, xPerc);

                    yPerc = Math.max(0, yPerc);
                    yPerc = Math.min(100 - this.handleHeight, yPerc);


                    var containerDim = viewerss.containerDim,
                        imgWidth = viewerss.imageDim.w * (viewerss.zoomValue / 100),
                        imgHeight = viewerss.imageDim.h * (viewerss.zoomValue / 100),
                        imgLeft = imgWidth < containerDim.w ? (containerDim.w - imgWidth) / 2 : -imgWidth * xPerc / 100,
                        imgTop = imgHeight < containerDim.h ? (containerDim.h - imgHeight) / 2 : -imgHeight * yPerc / 100;

                    snapHandle.css({
                        top: yPerc + '%',
                        left: xPerc + '%'
                    })

                    viewerss.currentImg.css({
                        left: imgLeft,
                        top: imgTop
                    })

                    viewerss.compareImg.css({
                        left: imgLeft,
                        top: imgTop
                    })
                }
            }).init();


            /*Add slide interaction to image*/
            var imageSlider = viewerss._imageSlider = new Slider(imageWrap, {
                sliderId: viewerss._viewerId,
                onStart: function (e, position) {
                    if (!viewerss.loaded) return false;
                    if (zooming) return;
                    var self = this;
                    snapSlider.onStart();
                    self.imgWidth = viewerss.imageDim.w * viewerss.zoomValue / 100;
                    self.imgHeight = viewerss.imageDim.h * viewerss.zoomValue / 100;

                    self.positions = [position, position];

                    self.startPosition = position;

                },
                onMove: function (e, position) {
                    if (zooming) return;
                    this.currentPos = position;

                    snapSlider.onMove(e, {
                        dx: -position.dx * snapSlider.width / this.imgWidth,
                        dy: -position.dy * snapSlider.height / this.imgHeight
                    });
                },

            }).init();

            /*Add zoom interation in mouse wheel*/
            var changedDelta = 0;
            imageWrap.on("mousewheel" + eventSuffix + " DOMMouseScroll" + eventSuffix, function (e) {

                if(!options.zoomOnMouseWheel) return;

                if (!viewerss.loaded) return;


                //clear all animation frame and interval
                viewerss._clearFrames();

                // cross-browser wheel delta
                var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail))),
                    zoomValue = viewerss.zoomValue * (100 + delta * ZOOM_CONSTANT) / 100;

                if(!(zoomValue >= 100 && zoomValue <= options.maxZoom)){
                    changedDelta += Math.abs(delta);
                }
                else{
                    changedDelta = 0;
                }

                if(changedDelta > MOUSE_WHEEL_COUNT) return;

                e.preventDefault();

                var contOffset = container.offset(),
                    x = (e.pageX || e.originalEvent.pageX) - contOffset.left,
                    y = (e.pageY || e.originalEvent.pageY) - contOffset.top;



                viewerss.zoom(zoomValue, {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                });
            });

            //zoom in zoom out using zoom handle
            var slider = viewerss.snapView.find('.iv-zoom-slider-ss');
            var zoomSlider = new Slider(slider, {
                sliderId: viewerss._viewerId,
                onStart: function (eStart) {

                    if (!viewerss.loaded) return false;

                    this.leftOffset = slider.offset().left;
                    this.handleWidth = viewerss.zoomHandle.width();
                    this.onMove(eStart);

                },
                onMove: function (e, position) {
                    var newLeft = (e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX) - this.leftOffset - this.handleWidth / 2;

                    newLeft = Math.max(0, newLeft);
                    newLeft = Math.min(viewerss._zoomSliderLength, newLeft);

                    var zoomValue = 100 + (options.maxZoom - 100) * newLeft / viewerss._zoomSliderLength;

                    viewerss.zoom(zoomValue);

                }
            }).init();

            //calculate elments size on window resize
            if (options.refreshOnResize) $window.on('resize' + eventSuffix, function () {
                //viewerss.refresh()
            });

        },

        //method to zoom images
        zoom: function (perc, point) {
            perc = Math.max(100, perc);

            if ((mouse_hover_depth & show_snap_view) | (!show_snap_view & hover_my & !hover_hang2)){
                point = {
                    x: point_x_depth,
                    y: point_y_depth
                };
                console.log("check run if");
                console.log("containerDim 00: "+this.containerDim.w);
            }else{
                console.log("check run else");
                point = point || {
                    x: this.containerDim.w / 2,
                    y: this.containerDim.h / 2
                };
                console.log("containerDim 01: "+this.containerDim.w);
                console.log("containerDim 02: "+this.containerDim.h);
            }

            point_x_ir = point.x;
            point_y_ir = point.y;

            var self = this,
                maxZoom = this.options.maxZoom,
                curPerc = this.zoomValue,
                curImg = this.currentImg,
                compareImg = this.compareImg,
                containerDim = this.containerDim,
                curLeft = parseFloat(curImg.css('left')),
                curTop = parseFloat(curImg.css('top'));
                console.log("containerDim 1: "+containerDim);


            self._clearFrames();

            var step = 0;

            //calculate base top,left,bottom,right
            var containerDim = self.containerDim,
                imageDim = self.imageDim;
                console.log("self.imageDim: "+self.imageDim);
                console.log("self.containerDim 2: "+self.containerDim);
                console.log("containerDim 2: "+containerDim);
            var baseLeft = (containerDim.w - imageDim.w) / 2,
                baseTop = (containerDim.h - imageDim.h) / 2,
                baseRight = containerDim.w - baseLeft,
                baseBottom = containerDim.h - baseTop;

            function zoom() {
                step++;

                if (step < 20) {
                    self._zoomFrame = requestAnimationFrame(zoom);
                }

                var tickZoom = Math.min(maxZoom, easeOutQuart(step, curPerc, perc - curPerc, 20));

                var ratio = tickZoom / curPerc,
                    imgWidth = self.imageDim.w * tickZoom / 100,
                    imgHeight = self.imageDim.h * tickZoom / 100,
                    newLeft = -((point.x - curLeft) * ratio - point.x),
                    newTop = -((point.y - curTop) * ratio - point.y);
                
                /
                //fix for left and top
                newLeft = Math.min(newLeft, baseLeft);
                newTop = Math.min(newTop, baseTop);

                //fix for right and bottom
                if((newLeft + imgWidth) < baseRight){
                    newLeft = (self.containerDim.w - imgWidth) ; //newLeft - (newLeft + imgWidth - baseRig
                }

                if((newTop + imgHeight) < baseBottom){
                    newTop = (self.containerDim.h - imgHeight) ; //newLeft - (newLeft + imgWidth - baseRig
                }

                curImg.css({
                    height: imgHeight + 'px',
                    width: imgWidth + 'px',
                    left: newLeft + 'px',
                    top: newTop + 'px'
                });

                compareImg.css({
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: imgWidth + 'px',
                    left: newLeft + 'px',
                    top: newTop + 'px'
                });

                self.zoomValue = tickZoom;

                self._resizeHandle(imgWidth, imgHeight, newLeft, newTop);

        
                //update zoom handle position
                self.zoomHandle.css('left', ((tickZoom - 100) * self._zoomSliderLength) / (maxZoom - 100) + 'px');
            }

            zoom();
        },

        _clearFrames: function () {
            //clearInterval(this._imageSlider.slideMomentumCheck);
            cancelAnimationFrame(this._imageSlider.sliderMomentumFrame);
            cancelAnimationFrame(this._zoomFrame)
        },
        //ko có vẫn chạy đc
        resetZoom: function () {
            this.zoom(this.options.zoomValue);
        },

        //calculate dimensions of image, container and reset the image
        _calculateDimensions: function () {
            //calculate content width of image and snap image
            var self = this,
                curImg = self.currentImg,
                compareImg = self.compareImg,
                container = self.container,
                snapView = self.snapView,
                imageWidth = curImg.width(),
                imageHeight = curImg.height(),
                contWidth = container.width(),
                contHeight = container.height(),
                snapViewWidth = snapView.innerWidth(),
                snapViewHeight = snapView.innerHeight();

            //set the container dimension
            self.containerDim = {
                w: contWidth,
                h: contHeight
            }

            //set the image dimension
            var imgWidth, imgHeight, ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

            imgWidth = (imageWidth > imageHeight && contHeight >= contWidth) || ratio * contHeight > contWidth ? contWidth : ratio * contHeight;

            imgHeight = imgWidth / ratio;

            self.imageDim = {
                w: imgWidth,
                h: imgHeight
            }

            compareImg.css({
                width: imgWidth + 'px',
                height: 'auto',
                left: (contWidth - imgWidth) / 2 + 'px',
                top: (contHeight - imgHeight) / 2 + 'px',
                'max-width': 'none',
                'max-height': 'none'
            });
            curImg.css({
                width: imgWidth + 'px',
                height: imgHeight + 'px',
                left: (contWidth - imgWidth) / 2 + 'px',
                top: (contHeight - imgHeight) / 2 + 'px',
                'max-width': 'none',
                'max-height': 'none'
            });

            //set the snap Image dimension
            var snapWidth = imgWidth > imgHeight ? snapViewWidth : imgWidth * snapViewHeight / imgHeight,
                snapHeight = imgHeight > imgWidth ? snapViewHeight : imgHeight * snapViewWidth / imgWidth;

            //ko có cũng ko sao
            self.snapImageDim = {
                w: snapWidth,
                h: snapHeight
            }
            self.snapImg.css({
                width: snapWidth,
                height: snapHeight
            });

            //calculate zoom slider area
            self._zoomSliderLength = snapViewWidth - self.zoomHandle.outerWidth();

        },

        refresh: function () {
            if (!this.loaded) return;
            this._calculateDimensions();
            this.resetZoom();
        },
        _resizeHandle: function (imgWidth, imgHeight, imgLeft, imgTop) {
            var curImg = this.currentImg,
                imageWidth = imgWidth || this.imageDim.w * this.zoomValue / 100,
                imageHeight = imgHeight || this.imageDim.h * this.zoomValue / 100,
                left = Math.max(-(imgLeft || parseFloat(curImg.css('left'))) * 100 / imageWidth, 0),
                top = Math.max(-(imgTop || parseFloat(curImg.css('top'))) * 100 / imageHeight, 0),
                handleWidth = Math.min(this.containerDim.w * 100 / imageWidth, 100),
                handleHeight = Math.min(this.containerDim.h * 100 / imageHeight, 100);

            this.snapHandle.css({
                top: top + '%',
                left: left + '%',
                width: handleWidth + '%',
                height: handleHeight + '%'
            });
        },
        load: function (image, hiResImg, compare, hiResCompare) {
            var self = this,
                container = this.container;

            container.find('.iv-snap-image-ss,.iv-large-image-ss').remove();
            var snapImageWrap = this.container.find('.iv-snap-image-wrap-ss');
            snapImageWrap.prepend('<img class="iv-snap-image-ss" style="width:120px; height: 90px;" src="' + image + '" />');
            this.imageWrap.prepend('<img class="iv-large-image-ss" src="' + image + '" />');

            if (hiResImg) {
                this.imageWrap.append('<img class="iv-large-image-ss" src="' + hiResImg + '" />')
            }

            if(compare) {
                this.imageWrap.append('<img class="iv-large-compare-ss" src="' + compare + '" />');
            }

            var currentImg = this.currentImg = this.container.find('.iv-large-image-ss');
            var compareImg = this.compareImg = this.container.find('.iv-large-compare');
            this.snapImg = this.container.find('.iv-snap-image-ss');
            self.loaded = false;

            //show loader
            container.find('.iv-loader-ss').show();
            currentImg.hide();
            compareImg.css('opacity', 0);
            self.snapImg.hide();

            //refresh the view
            function refreshView() {
                self.loaded = true;
                self.zoomValue = 100;

                //reset zoom of images
                currentImg.show();
                self.snapImg.show();
                self.refresh();
                self.resetZoom();

                //hide loader
                container.find('.iv-loader-ss').hide();
            }

            if (imageLoaded(currentImg[0])) {
                refreshView();
            } else {
                $(currentImg[0]).on('load', refreshView);
            }

        },
        setCompareAlpha: function(alpha) {
            /*Add shift binding for image compare toggle*/
            this.compareImg.css('opacity', alpha)
        }
    }

    ImageViewerss.defaults = {
        zoomValue: 100,
        snapView: true,
        maxZoom: 300,
        refreshOnResize: true,
        zoomOnMouseWheel : true
    }

    window.ImageViewerss = function (container, options) {
        var imgElm, imgSrc, compareElm, compareSrc, hiResImg, hiResCompare;
        if (!(container && (typeof container == "string" || container instanceof Element || container[0] instanceof Element))) {
            options = container;
            container = $('#iv-container-ss');
        }

        container = $(container);

        if (container.is('img')) {
            imgElm = container;
            imgSrc = imgElm[0].src;
            hiResImg = imgElm.attr('high-res-src') || imgElm.attr('data-high-res-src');
            container = imgElm.wrap('<div class="iv-container-ss" style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden"></div>').parent();
            imgElm.css({
                opacity: 0,
                position: 'relative',
                zIndex: -1
            });
        } else {
            imgSrc = container.attr('src') || container.attr('data-src');
            compareSrc = container.attr('compare-src') || container.attr('data-compare-src');
            hiResImg = container.attr('high-res-src') || container.attr('data-high-res-src');
        }


        var viewerss = new ImageViewerss(container, options);
        viewerss._init();

        if (imgSrc) viewerss.load(imgSrc, hiResImg, compareSrc, hiResCompare);

        return viewerss;
    };

}((window.jQuery), window, document));
```

Here is the error code(The error line is the first line of the code below) :

```js
 //calculate base top,left,bottom,right
 var containerDim = self.containerDim,
    imageDim = self.imageDim;
    console.log("self.imageDim: "+self.imageDim);
    console.log("self.containerDim 2: "+self.containerDim);
    console.log("containerDim 2: "+containerDim);
 var baseLeft = (containerDim.w - imageDim.w) / 2,
    baseTop = (containerDim.h - imageDim.h) / 2,
    baseRight = containerDim.w - baseLeft,
    baseBottom = containerDim.h - baseTop;
```

I'm call it like this:

```js
if (mouseDown) {
   ismouse = true
} else {
     if (ismouse) {
        $('.iv-large-image-ss').css('top', $('.iv-large-image').css('top'));
        $('.iv-large-image-ss').css('left', $('.iv-large-image').css('left'));
        ismouse = false
     }
     viewerss.zoom(rate);
}
```

"rate" is a number that I want to assign to represent the zoom level.

Comment: You have to provide more details than that. Where do you see the error? What could be the possible problem in your code that may causing the problem. Lastly, don't add code in image when you're posting a question in SO.

Comment: Are you referring to the `window` object with `this`? What is the `self.containerDim`?

Comment: @RifatBinReza self.containerDim is the image source that I assigned to it.